# Where does Lincoln say the South wants us to believe as they believe?

Tags: quotes, abraham-lincoln

I can no longer find this article or speech, written by Lincoln in which he says argues that the North had done everything in its power to accommodate the South, but the South was still not appeased because they wanted not just that the North allowed them their way, but also that the North should agree with them wholeheartedly that slavery was right and moral, and until the North did so the South would not be happy.

That is of course a summary, but I would like to find the full text to quote from.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The speech was in 1860 when Lincoln was seeking the Republican nomination for president. He was addressing the problem of the slave states, whose rebellion was already foreseen.

> These natural, and apparently adequate means all failing, what will convince them? This, and this only: cease to call slavery wrong, and join them in calling it right. And this must be done thoroughly - done in acts as well as in words. Silence will not be tolerated - we must place ourselves avowedly with them. *[Wikipedia:CooperUnionSpeech](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper_Union_speech)*

From that article:

> The Cooper Union speech or address, known at the time as the Cooper Institute speech,[1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper_Union_speech) was delivered by Abraham Lincoln on February 27, 1860, at Cooper Union, in New York City. Lincoln was not yet the Republican nominee for the presidency, as the convention was scheduled for May. It is considered one of his most important speeches. Some historians have argued that the speech was responsible for his victory in the presidential election later that year.[2]
> Photo of Abraham Lincoln taken February 27, 1860 in New York City by Mathew Brady, the day of his famous Cooper Union speech

> In the speech, Lincoln elaborated his views on slavery by affirming that he did not wish it to be expanded into the western territories and claiming that the Founding Fathers would agree with this position.